# Default location of web site content

Tags: debian, apache2

I am looking to install [MediaWiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MediaWiki) on a production server (after doing a test on a development one). I could not really understand why the default location for the MediaWiki files is `/var/lib/mediawiki`. I would have thought `/var/www` would've made more sense.

I did some research and in *[Ubuntu Policy Manual, Chapter 11 - Customized programs, 11.5 Web servers and applications](http://people.canonical.com/~cjwatson/ubuntu-policy/policy.html/ch-customized-programs.html#s-web-appl)* it says the following.

> Web Document Root
>
> Web Applications should try to avoid storing files in the Web Document Root. Instead >they should use the /usr/share/doc/package directory for documents and register the Web >Application via the doc-base package. If access to the web document root is unavoidable >then use
>
> ```
> /var/www
> ```

Why is this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question here. To me it sounds like you're wondering why it's stored in '/usr/share/doc/package` instead of '/var/www` - and to my knowledge, it's fairly easy to edit the apache config files.

Answer (score 3):

It appears that we [inherit this policy](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-customized-programs.html) from Debian. The closest discussion I can seem to find on this policy is from this [discussion](http://lists.debian.org/debian-policy/2003/12/msg00004.html) in 2003.

However I did find a [new draft policy](http://webapps-common.alioth.debian.org/draft/html/ch-issues.html) (Check out section 3.1) that appears to have more detail which might help solve your question. It specifically mentions the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard). According to that `/usr/share/doc` includes "Architecture-independent (shared) data.", which includes web pages that user's can't modify.

Since Mediawiki is user editable `/var/lib/mediawiki` would be the place for it to go since the FHS says that `/var/lib` is the place for "State information. Persistent data modified by programs as they run, e.g., databases, packaging system metadata, etc.
" and the manual says:

> User uploaded content
>
> A unique subdirectory of /var/lib/PACKAGE

The rest of the section in the manual explains architecture dependent things (like PHP and Perl).

This information is marked Draft however so I am not sure if it's enforced or pending in Debian. I would expect that if this were the final policy that we would likely inherit it from Debian.

So I guess the partial answer is "The FHS says so and Debian follows it so we do." I (unfortunately) cannot find any information on the justification/reasons why the FHS is the way it is in this regard, maybe someone else will have better luck finding this information and adding an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Your custom content indeed goes to `/var/www` - where you can edit files, move them around, etc.

However, PHP (and other) applications from the package repositories may install their internal libraries to `/usr/share/packagename` and `/var/lib/packagename` to better fit in with other (non-web) applications. [See this list of MediaWiki package contents](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/all/mediawiki/filelist).

Also, packages may publish their [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) (and other) documentation on your local webserver if you are running one. Apache 2's default configuration on Ubuntu allows access to system documentation from localhost under the `/doc` directory. However, this is another topic.

Comment: I think he's just looking for an explanation of the policy.

Comment: My reason for asking the question is that to me the /var folder is for things like logs and a folder /lib would be for things like libraries. /var/lib just felt like it was the wrong folder and I was tempted to put my wiki in a different location but thanks for two excellent answers. I'll leave it in the default location now.